Calling module from jupyter notebook inside of poetry project reults in 'No module named' error
I'm working on a module with poetry with a directory structure like
./
   /my_module
      (module files)
   /tests
      test_thing.py
   /jupyter
      demo.ipynb

In the test files and jupyter notebooks there is import code like
from my_module import thingy, other_thingy

Now from the project root poetry run pytest works without issue, but invoking jupyter lab via poetry run jupyter lab and then running the notebook results in No module named my_module error. Why is the module on the path for pytest and not jupyter?
Of course I can do the following, but then none of the other modules from the poetry env are available. How can I resolve this?
import sys
sys.path.append('../)


Solved it. This issue arises when jupyter is not installed using poetry within the project. Simply poetry add jupyter (to whatever group) and then poetry run jupyter lab gives the expected result. Otherwise it silently falls back on the system installed version of jupyter lab.
